# Getting `Could not find com.google.firebase:firebase-core:.` error in flutter add-to-app

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, gradle, flutter-add-to-app

I'm trying to integrate a Flutter app with the add-to-app feature following the Official documentation which is outdated as per [this](https://github.com/flutter/flutter-intellij/issues/5914) thread. In my Flutter part's pubspec.yaml, I have this Dependency Library - `firebase_core: ^2.4.1`
And in my Android Project's App level build.gradle file, I have this -

```
implementation(platform("com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:31.0.3"))
implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-core")
```

I was using 31.2.0, but since I started getting this error, I switched to 31.0.3 since that's what Flutter's package was using.

When I run `flutter build aar` and Sync android project the with Gradle, I get these errors -
[image]

And when I just try to run the app, I see this -
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Go to android->app->build.gradle and use `implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:21.1.1"` instead of `"com.google.firebase:firebase-core:"`. In my case that was the solution.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I'm having similar issue as well firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup

This page states that we don't need to add version if we use firebase-bom.
[image: firebase setup]

However, if we refer to https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases

we can see the dependencies in the firebase-bom.

For example, com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.8.0 doesn't have firebase-core listed.

As for firebase-bom:31.0.3

https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android#2022-11-11

It doesn't include firebase-core as well.

Note:
[image: firebase update]